# how to fix error on

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, opensql

I have sql request

```
DELETE FROM BC_UDV3_ROLES 
WHERE PERMISSION_ID = 'x' OR
      0 < (SELECT * FROM BC_UDV3_ROLES 
           WHERE "SUBSTR"(PERMISSION_ID, 0, 1)='D')  OR '1'='1'
```

when I execute it get  this error

Please help, how I can fix it?

Comment: how about just doing a truncate table, that is, you have where 1=1

Comment: Why have you put `"` around `SUBSTR`?  And, as per @Drew, why on earth have you got `<condition> OR <condition> OR '1'='1'`?  *(The first two conditions are now irrelevant, `'1'` **always** equals `'1'`, and so the whole expression is **always** TRUE)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM BC_UDV3_ROLES
WHERE PERMISSION_ID = 'x'
OR 0 < (SELECT count(*) FROM BC_UDV3_ROLES WHERE SUBSTRING(PERMISSION_ID, 1, 1)='D')
```

`OR '1'='1'` condition always evaluates to TRUE. it is not needed.

Also if you are using `mysql` the function should be `substring` instead of `substr`. Also there should be no quotes around the function name.
You can't compare `0` with all the columns in the table. Use a `count(*)` instead.

Alternately you can also try

```
DELETE FROM BC_UDV3_ROLES
WHERE PERMISSION_ID = 'x'
OR SUBSTRING(PERMISSION_ID, 1, 1)='D'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `SUBSTR` in a wrong way. Try this:

```
DELETE FROM BC_UDV3_ROLES WHERE PERMISSION_ID = 'x' OR
0<(SELECT * FROM BC_UDV3_ROLES WHERE SUBSTR(PERMISSION_ID, 0,
1)='D')  OR '1'='1'
```